# how to use variables in SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have an xml file with line below

```
<config-root>/temp</config-root>
```

Using  'sed' is bash shell script I want to replace the line, 
the 'sed' script is below

```
sed -i 's/<config-root>\(.*\)<\/config-root>/<config-root>\"${dirPath}"<\/config-root>/' Plan.xml
```

The 'sed' is resulting in

```
<config-root>"${dirPath}"</config-root>
```

I am expecting the line to be replaced as  /opt/shared

Can anyone let me know what is wrong in my script? Basically I want to use variable in ‘sed’

Thanks in advance,
Babu

Comment: Use `-r` or `-E` switch to enable ERE. Use different delimiters to avoid crazy escaping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash to place the variable in the `sed` script: End the sed script using the single quote `'`, place the variable in double quotes `"` and continue the `sed` program with another single quote `'`:

```
sed 's~<config-root>[^<]*</config-root>~<config-root>'"$variable"'</config-root>~' Plan.xml
```

I would encourage you to use delimiter different from `/` because the `/` is part of the pattern (and of the variable) and would need to get escaped otherwise. I used `~` as the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you , with your suggestion it is working